# Unable to convert Month-Year string to Date in R

Tags: r

I'm using `as.Date` to convert a string like `Aug-2002` to a dates object representing just the month of Aug of 2002, or if a day must be specified, Aug 1, 2002.

However

```
> as.Date(c('07-2002'), "%M-%Y")
[1] "2002-11-06"

> as.Date(c('Aug-2002'), "%b-%Y")
[1] NA
```

Why does the first line of code convert it to a different month and day? And the second one is `NA`?

I referred to [this table](http://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html) for the formatting symbols.

[image]

Comment: %M is iminutes. %m is month.

Comment: "%b Abbreviated month name in the **current locale on this platform**." And you must specify the day to get a `Date`.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Is the table i referred to in the question the wrong table?

Comment: The second argument of that function is for the format of your date. You supplied `"%M-%Y"`. Therefore, you indicated that you have a date in the form "MINUTES hyphen 4-digit YEAR". But that is not the form of your data. You have the form "MONTH hyphen YEAR", so you need to supply that format `"%m-%Y"`.

Comment: From within R `?strptime` gets you to the help page for the percent codes.

Answer (score 13):

The problem you are having is that the dates you have do not have a day value. Without the day value the `format="%m-%Y"` will not work in `as.Date`. These options below will solve them:

```
as.Date(paste0('01-', c('07-2002')), format="%d-%m-%Y")

library(zoo) #this is a little more forgiving:
as.yearmon(c('07-2002'), "%m-%Y")
as.yearmon(c('Aug-2002'), "%b-%Y")

as.Date(as.yearmon(c('07-2002'), "%m-%Y"))
```